# Backbone.js - How is the View finding this Collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm going through a tutorial to learn how to use Backbone.js and I'm having a hard time understanding how Backbone views are "seeing" the collection.

**Below is the View code, and underneath that is the Collection code.**

I can see that the variable $albums is being assigned to the particular class '.albums' that is within the element, but I don't get how this code is referencing 'this.collection'.

Both the view and the collection are being extended from standard Backbone.View and Backbone.Collection classes.  Just from looking at it, I can't see how they even know each other exist.  I'm assuming that the word 'this' refers to this particular instance of LibraryView.

I guess this is my primary question:

How is it that the code `collection = this.collection` is able to see the external collection?

```
// A wrapper view to display each album in Library
    window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({         
        tagName: 'section',
        className: 'library',

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.template = _.template($('#library-template').html());
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },

        render: function() {            
            var $albums,
                collection = this.collection;           

            $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
            $albums = this.$('.albums');
            collection.each(function(album) {
                var view = new LibraryAlbumView({
                    model: album,
                    collection: collection
                });
                $albums.append(view.render().el);
            });
            return this;
        }

    });
```

Here is the Albums collection:

```
// Albums Collection
    window.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Album,
        url: '/albums'
    })
```

**EDIT:**

---

I think I found it thanks to the help here:

There was another piece of code creating a library variable and assigning it to a new albums collection:

```
window.library = new Albums();
```

Also, in the Router there is an initialize statement that passes in the 'library' variable:

```
initialize: function() {
            this.libraryView = new LibraryView({
                collection: window.library
            });
```

Now it seems to make more sense.  :)

Just posting this in case someone else is as confused as I was.

Comment: Find the place where you initialize the view (in Router?). There you're probably passing in the collection.

Comment: I'm following the Peepcode tutorial too! and had exactly the same question. I believe the confusion comes from a leap in the video where the views were previously constructed in the Chrome's console but the video cuts and the collection is assigned in the Router constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A collection would have to be passed to the LibraryView constructor. For example,

```
myLibrary = new LibraryView({
  collection: new Albums()
})
```

However, an important bit of magic happens here. Everything passed to a View constructor ends up in the View's `options` property. A select number of properties though, get copied over on to the view itself. So you can say `this.collection` instead of `this.options.collection`.

Those special properties are:

'model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName'

Comment: Thanks Max - I edited my original post to show what the issue was in case someone else has the same question.